jq select multiple elements from an array
I have a JSON which looks like:
{
  "type": "server-firmwareinventory-list-1",
  "members": [
    {
      "type": "sever-hardware-firmware-1",
      "category": "sever-hardware",
      "serverName": "my-host",
      "components": [
        {
          "componentName": "firmware-hdd-8051bb7e9c",
          "componentDescription": "VS000480KXALB, VS003840KWXFQ, VS001920KWXFP, and VS000960KWXFN Drives firmware",
          "componentVersion": "85032G00-4.1"
        },
        {
          "componentName": "System ROM",
          "componentDescription": "SystemRomActive",
          "componentVersion": "A46 v2.80 (07/31/2023)"
        },
        {
          "componentName": "Redundant System ROM",
          "componentDescription": "SystemRomBackup",
          "componentVersion": "A46 v2.60 (08/11/20223)"
        }
      ],
    "serverFirmwareSettings": null
    }
  ]
}

I can successfully get the active system ROM for each server with (${FIRMW} points to the file holding the JSON).
jq -r '.members[] | {"serverName": .serverName, "system-firmware": .components[] | select(.componentName=="System ROM") | .componentVersion }' ${FIRMW}

I wanted to add the redundant system ROM, so I tried:
jq -r '.members[] | {"serverName": .serverName, "system-firmware": .components[] | select(.componentName=="System ROM") | .componentVersion, "system-firmware-backup": | select(.componentName=="Redundant System ROM") | .componentVersion }' ${FIRMW}

but that gets me a syntax error, unexpected '|' at line 1.  Any ideas how to fix this?

I think I am getting a little closer with:
.members[]  | .components[] | select(.componentName | contains("ROM"))
but need to create my output JSON with the name and just the firmware versions.

What do you want the results to look like?

Are you looking for {"componentName":"System ROM","componentVersion":"A46 v2.80 (07/31/2023)"} {"componentName":"Redundant System ROM","componentVersion":"A46 v2.60 (08/11/20223)"} ? If not, what?

You forgot to filter the compontents array when selecting for Redundant System ROM.
A corrected variant of your code with some shortcuts added (note that -r is unneeded as you are outputting JSON, not raw strings):
jq '.members[] |
    {
        serverName,
        "system-firmware":
            .components[] | select(.componentName == "System ROM").componentVersion,
        "system-firmware-backup":
            .components[] | select(.componentName == "Redundant System ROM").componentVersion
    }' file

Given the data in the question, this would give you the following JSON document:
{
  "serverName": "my-host",
  "system-firmware": "A46 v2.80 (07/31/2023)",
  "system-firmware-backup": "A46 v2.60 (08/11/20223)"
}


Not entirely sure whether I guessed right with the OP's required output..?

@ChrisDavies Since their code is largely correct and only really lacked that second .components[], I'm assuming their expected output is {"serverName":"my-host","system-firmware":"A46 v2.80 (07/31/2023)","system-firmware-backup":"A46 v2.60 (08/11/20223)"}.
